# Named vs nameless function for replacing numbers in a string

Tags: javascript

I am a JavaScript beginner, and one of the problems in the latest programming assignment I got is to replace all numbers in a string with sum of their digits, so, for example, for an input like this:

```
"m123a"
```

the output should be

```
"m6a"
```

I actually managed to write a working code, but I do not understand why it works.

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
  <TEXTAREA ID = "text" ROWS = 10 COLS = 30></TEXTAREA>
  <br>
  <INPUT TYPE = "button" ID = "button" VALUE = "Replace">
  <SCRIPT src = "zaz3.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
</html>
```

This is my working JavaScript code:

```
function ReplaceNumbers()
{
  var s = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.getElementById("text").value = s.replace(/\d+/g, function DigitSum(x)
  {
    var sum = 0;
    while (x > 0)
    {
      sum += x%10;
      x = x/10;
      x = Math.floor(x);
    }
    return sum;
  });
}

var button = document.getElementById( "button");

button.addEventListener("click" , ReplaceNumbers);
```

And this is the first version of my JavaScript code which does not work:

```
function DigitSum(x)
{
  var sum = 0;
  while (x > 0)
  {
    sum += x%10;
    x = x/10;
    x = Math.floor(x);
  }
  return sum;
}

function ReplaceNumbers()
{
  var s = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.getElementById("text").value = s.replace(/\d+/g, DigitSum(x));
}

var button = document.getElementById( "button");

button.addEventListener("click" , ReplaceNumbers);
```

The only difference here is that function `DigitSum` is implemented separately in the second version.

When debugging the second code, the error returned is `"ReferenceError: x is not defined".` I do not understand how the parameter `x` in the first code is even interpreted since it's not mentioned anywhere else in the code.

So, my question is, what is the difference between implementing the function DigitSum separately vs implementing it where it is needed, and what actually is `x` in the first version, and what is it in the second version.

Comment: In the non-working version try replacing DigitSum(x) with just DigitSum. DigitSum(x) will actually call the function with the undefined variable x. DigitSum will just return a reference to the function.

Comment: *"I do not understand how the parameter 'x' in the first code is even interpreted since it's not mentioned anywhere else in the code"* It is defined as a function parameter, so that *is* its declaration. You're not using it in the parameter position, you're *defining* it there. `function DigitSum(x) { console.log(x) }` So the first `x` declares the parameter and the second one uses it.

Answer (score 1):

because in the second one you are calling the function and whatever it returns is being assigned to the replace. In your case you should have an error that says "x is undefined".

```
document.getElementById("text").value = s.replace(/\d+/g, DigitSum(x));
```

It should just be

```
document.getElementById("text").value = s.replace(/\d+/g, DigitSum);
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a callback

```
document.getElementById("text").value = s.replace(/\d+/g, DigitSum(x));
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but instead to use only the function reference, you insert a call of the function with `x`, which does not exist.

Use this for a valid reference of a callback.

```
document.getElementById("text").value = s.replace(/\d+/g, DigitSum);
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^ without parenthesis
```

A calback is a function which is used for repeating calls with a fixed parameter list. The surrounding function defines the parameters and in this case you may have a look to [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: In the working case, can the code be understood as "pass the current number in string to the function in the second parameter"?

Comment: And sorry for double post, but is DigitSum in my working code also treated as a callback?

Comment: yes. basically for every match of the regex, the callback is called with the parameters according of the API of replace. your `DigitSum` is a callback in the first part, too. You could omit the function name.

Comment: I understand the problem now, thank you very much for your time.